# Stitch Part Files to one with custom name

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

Data Fusion Pipeline gives us one or more part files at output if sync in GCS Bucket. My question is how we can combine those part files to one and also gave them a meaningful name ?

Comment: Are you using GCS Multi File?

Comment: no normal GCS File

Comment: Can you show how it is configured in your environment?

Comment: Hi Esteves, 
you can check the configurations set at below link
https://storage.googleapis.com/falcons_soco_args/Screenshot_2020-08-28%20Cloud%20Data%20Fusion%20Studio.png

Answer (score 2):

The `Data Fusion` transformations run in `Dataproc` clusters executing either `Spark` or `MapReduce` jobs. Your final output is split in many files because the jobs partition your data based on the HDFS partitions (this is the default behavior for Spark/Hadoop).

When writing a Spark script you are able to manipulate this default behavior and produce different outputs. However, Data Fusion was built to abstract the code layer and provide you the experience of using a fully managed data integrator. Using split files should not be a problem but if you really need to merge them I suggest that you use the following approach:

1. On the top of your Pipeline Studio click on **Hub** -> **Plugins**, search for **Dynamic Spark Plugin**, click on **Deploy** and then in **Finish** (you can ignore the JAR file)
2. Back to your pipeline, select **Spark** in the sink section.
3. Replace your **GCS** plugin with the **Spark** plugin
4. In your Spark plugin, set **Compile at Deployment Time** as **false** and replace the code with some Spark code that does what you want. The code below for example is hardcoded but works:

   ```
    def sink(df: DataFrame) : Unit = {
      new_df = df.coalesce(1)
      new_df.write.format("csv").save("gs://your/path/")
    }
   ```

   This function receives the data from your pipeline as a **Dataframe**. The **coalesce** function reduces the number of partitions to 1 and the last line writes it to GCS.
5. Deploy your pipeline and it will be ready to run

Comment: Hi Esteves,

Thanks for the answer, but if we are going to reduce the partitions to 1, will it move the data into one worker node ? and will put load on one node ?

Comment: @SUDHIRGARG You are correct. This approach will be more time consuming than the other one for this reason. Unfortunately this is the only approach for doing that directly. Another approach could be a separate process to merge the files

Comment: @SUDHIRGARG if it helped you in the end, consider upvoting